# tinyMCE setContent strips closing p-tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

i want to put the content from a database field to the tinyMCE editor on page load. For that i've got a php function like this:

```
public function __loadTinyMCE($jobscopeIntroText) {
    print '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadDefaultTinyMCEContent(){
             tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("'.$jobscopeIntroText.'", {format : "raw"});
        }
    </script>
    ';
```

`$jobscopeIntroText` is the html content i previously wrote into the tinyMCE editor and comes from the database.

When i write e.g.:

```
<p>Hello< /p>< p>This is a new line< /p>
```

it doesnt work and the html code in `setContent()` is broken after the *first closing* p-tag. In chrome developer tools the text before the first closing p-tag is red and after that it's black. Even if there are no " or ' within the html.
With only one closing p-tag it works.

Anyone knows the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I think  you should use this code once all contents will be loaded. Therefore there can be ways to achieve desire result:

1. You can place your database value within editor element and then
   initialize tinyMCE editor. (if page is loading)
2. You can above function just before the before the body tag ends.
3. You can use document load event or jQuery document.ready() function and just function within it.

I hope this will work for you. Please do let me know for specific scenario.

Comment: Thank you. As i said, the code works. I call the code on tiny.init. But somehow the html string is broken after the first </p>. I can find the error because there is none. But in chrome developer tools the html string before the first </p> is red and after the tag is black. But the string is within the "s.

Comment: I think you should try by removing "format" argument (As you already have the html). In addition, you can try to convert your database value into html using htmlentities() function.